# Additional tools/scripts/plugins for editing html with vim

Tags: html, vim, text-editor

I am looking for any pointers with regards to editing html with Vim.

The HTML documents I need to edit will use css (probably inline) but no JavaScript or any other "technique".

So, I thought there must be people more knowledgebale than me in that area that could give me some hints as to where I could find some tools, or scripts or Vim plugins that assist me while I am editing the documents.

FWIW, I am using Vim 7.3.

Answer (score 4):

I'm happy with [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540). It comes with a bunch of default snippets for many languages including HTML and JavaScript but they are easy to modify/augment: here is my customized [html.snippets](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/blob/master/snippets/html.snippets).

[SparkUp](https://github.com/bingaman/vim-sparkup) allows you to use compact CSS syntax to write massive amounts of HTML, it's a bit too rigid for my taste, though.

To be able to use Omni Completion for CSS you will need to change the "file type" setting for the buffer like this: `:set ft=css.html`.

Also Vim itself is very powerful for HTML even without fancy plugins:

- `cit` will remove `text` from `<p>text</p>` and leave you in insertion mode between the opening and closing tags
- `dat` will delete the whole `<p>text</p>`
- `:norm I` and `:norm A` let you append text at the beginning and end of multiple visually selected lines

and so on…

Comment: your html.snippets link is broken

Answer (score 2):

[RagTag](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1896) ([documentation](https://github.com/tpope/vim-ragtag/blob/master/doc/ragtag.txt)) is a nice plugin for HTML (and more) editing.

Also, [matchit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) to help navigate between an opening tag and its closing tag with '%'

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that this one is quite good, 
[HTML/XHTML mappings for Vim](http://christianrobinson.name/vim/HTML/)
it provides macros for templates, header insertion, tag insertion, and tag completion. It does supports inline CSS and includes commands to launch the a web browser and display the currently edited file.

Hope that's a start!

Kate.

Answer (score 1):

The [surround plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) is quite useful for HTML, it makes it a lot easier to add/delete/edit sets of tags, instead of having to deal with the opening and closing tags individually.

A good article about explaining some of the things you can do with it is here: [Vim Plugins You Should Know About, Part I: surround.vim](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-surround-vim/)

Comment: Yes, Surround's `cst<div>` is wonderful for turning `<p>text</p>` into `<div>text</div>`. That is so incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Zen plugin](http://mattn.github.com/zencoding-vim/) seems interesting to write HTML with minimal number of keystroke.

There is a nice video demonstrating how it works in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Check my `.vimrc` and `vim config` in my git repo at [github](https://github.com/jelera/dotfiles/tree/master/vim)

I've spend so many weeks tweaking Vim to suit my needs to do web development in a productive way.